# PHP: Add <span> to all <td> w/ no content?

Tags: php, html-table, tablesorter

I have a PHP-driven `<table>` that has multiple empty `<td>`s, and I want to add a `<span>` to each empty `<td>`. I specifically want this to occur:

-Add **`<span style="display: none">(empty)</span>`** to each empty `<td>`

How can I make that happen with PHP and not jQuery in the code posted below? This is the code that generates each `<td>`:

```
if ( is_array( $assign ) ) {
    $assign_users = '';
    if ( $layout == 'table' ) $this->list .= '<td class="todo-assigned">';
    foreach ( $assign as $value ) {
        if ( $value != '-1' && $value != '' && $value != 0 ) {
            $user = get_userdata( $value );
            $assign_users .= $user->display_name.', ';
        }
    }
    $this->list .= substr( $assign_users, 0, -2 );
    if ( $layout == 'table' ) $this->list .= '</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check `$assign_users` right before you add it to `$this->list`. If it's empty, add your span, otherwise the sub-string like you do now:

```
$this->list .= empty($assign_users) ? '<span.....>' : substr( $assign_users, 0, -2 );
```

Comment: You sir are a gentleman, and a scholar. Many, many thanks for the help. :)